# C#, Copying files from multiple all subdirectories to one directory

Tags: c#

So I made the mistake of letting iTunes manage my music, and now any song that has more than one artist is in a separate sub-directory.  I am trying to get all music files from all of the nested directories that iTunes created, and dump them into one folder so that I can use a more competent program to organize my music (no offense to iTunes fans).

I am aware of how to copy the directories to another location, as well as listing out the directories and sub directories as illustrated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)

My assumption is that I would have to list all directories, sub-directories, and contents of those directories, and then loop through each file string.

Is there a way to get a list of all files (not directories) within a directory tree to simplify the process?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The way the file system works requires polling each directory and sub-directory, looking for files.

Comment: +1 for "I made the mistake of letting iTunes manage my music" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `System.Io.Directory.GetFiles` with the overload for `SearchOptions`. That lets you specify searching all subdirectories.

Not sure if that is exactly what you are looking for, but should get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;

DirectoryInfo itunes = new DirectoryInfo("MyItunesPath");

FileInfo[] itunesFiles = 
    itunes.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Thank you, that should work.  I couldn't find the right search criteria to get this result.